# How to find the text value between special characters in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Very new to Ruby,

```
file_path = "/.../datasources/xml/data.txt"
```

How can I find the value between the last two forward slashes?  In this case that value is 'xml'...I can't use absolute positioning because the number of '/' will vary as will the text , but the value I need is always in between the last two /

I could only find examples on how to find a specific word in a string, but in this case I don't know the value of the word so those examples did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_path.split("/").fetch(-2)`

you said you're sure it's always between two last slashes. this splits your string into an array over slashes and then gets the second last element.

```
"/.../datasources/xml/data.txt".split("/").fetch(-2) => "xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ruby 1.9 or higher:

```
if subject =~ 
    /(?<=\/) # Assert that previous character is a slash
    [^\/]*   # Match any number of characters except slashes
    (?=      # Assert that the following text can be matched from here:
     \/      #  a slash,
     [^\/]*  #  followed by any number of characters except slashes
     \Z      # and the end of the string
    )        # End of lookahead assertion
    /x
    match = $&
```

Comment: @RaffiM: In that case, you can drop the `(?<=\/)` at the start, but then the regex would not make sure that there actually *are* at least two slashes in the string. If that's not a problem, the regex should be fine.